# What's the best tool or method to search for a specific word in a codebase?

Tags: search, command-line, replace

What tool or method do you recommend to find and replace values in your code? If code is on Linux/Unix, are find and grep the best method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [ack](http://petdance.com/ack/), which is designed for searching big codebases.

For replacing, look at Perl's -i, -p and -e flags.  You can do stuff like:

```
$ perl -i -p -e's/\bthisword\b/thatword/g' $(find . -name *.html)
```

to replace all instances of thisword with thatword in all .html files in the tree.

Comment: You could also use ack for the find part in your replace example: $ perl -i -p -e's/\bthisword\b/thatword/g' $(ack -f --html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you intend to rename a variable.

It depends on what the body of code is. For C#, Visual Studio's renaming tool is very good. Remember that for it to work reliably, you need the renaming to work hand in hand with the compiler/interpreter, so you can make sure you only make the change in the right scope.

If it is a very simple find/replace, surely the lowly notepad would do an OK job?

Answer (score 1):

`find` and `grep` will find the word you're looking for, but to replace it you need to use  `sed`, `awk` or your favorite stream editing filter.

`groovy`, `python`, `perl` will all do search/replace operations - use your favorite or pick one to learn.

For operations on a code base, I'll use `find | sed` for simple operations (`cygwin` is your friend) and the IDE's search/replace with regex support for more complex operations.  Eclipse, Idea, Visual Studio  and even SQL Server Manglement Studio have powerful search/replace functions.  The bad news is that not all of them use the same regex syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into PowerGrep... it has ads everywhere in SO. I'm starting to want it even when i don't really need it-

PD: They have a 15 days free demo, so if this is a small job you could just use the demo.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a tip to Andy's above accepted answer.could not add this as a comment due to less reputation

Use ! as a seperator when you have tough time escaping the strings

e.g $ perl -i -p -e's!\bthisword\b!thatword!g' $(find . -name *.html)

Answer (score 0):

find and grep don't build indecies, so they're always going to be slower than alternatives that do. That said, they work fine if your codebase is only a few dozen files.in Fi

Eclipse has a nice file search feature (Ctrl+H). It can also take language semantics into consideration if you have the right plugins (Java works out of the box, of course).  The only caveat is that it can be a bit slow the first time you search in a certain file set.